# Setting up a general afterEach test for all test specs

Tags: webdriver-io

Is there a way to set up a general `afterEach` test that will run after each of the tests are running?
(instead of configuring it repeatedly for each test file)

Answer (score 0):

Found it - you need to test the `afterTest` property to the desired function in the webio configuration file.
https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile/